# Get changes with Rebase

Tags: git, android-studio, merge, git-merge, rebase

I have **master**, **feature/ZM-6** (root of feature branch) and **task/ZM-222** (a task of same feature which created from ZM-6).

I added a commit to **feature/ZM-6**. I need to have that changes in all task branches without merge commit. For example task **task/ZM-222**.

I am using Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply rebase the branch on the updated base line

```
git fetch
git checkout task/ZM-222
git rebase feature/ZM-6
```

Now ZM-222 is based on the latest commit in ZM-6.